# AC Power Isolation

Tags: transformer, ac, power-electronics, isolation

I need to supply isolated AC power to some test equipment. As far as I know, isolation transformers are used to do this. However, to supply 40 Amps from 220VAC 50Hz as isolated power, the needed transformer becomes a 90kg giant which is not practical even in rack mount environment.

Is there any smaller, lighter, or more practical way to do this?

Comment: Single phase / three phase? Have you considered UPS or pure sine inverter? Neither will be cheap at 10 kW. Does the whole system need to be isolated or could you, for example, just isolate the control system or whatever ... Otherwise it's 90 kg of copper and iron.

Comment: Is this a lot of small devices or 1 or 2 big current devices?. For smaller devices individual isolating supplies might be a solution. For a one off that could be ok.

Comment: What is driving the requirement to provide isolated AC power to this equipment?  What sort of test equipment are we dealing with even?

Comment: If you embiggen your operating frequency you can ensmallen your transformers a bit.  Really transformers aren't too horrible though.  They make up for size, weight and cost with incredibly long service life and good efficiency.